# Using LayeredPane, changing background color of panes underneath brings them to the foreground?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, gui-builder

I'm making a piano interface and am trying to make it so that when the user clicks the white key it turns light gray, then when they release it. When I press the key, it beings the white key to the foreground and hides the black key.

Before clicking anything:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/gwZAbJV.png]

After clicking a few keys:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Ax7dw6w.png]

The keys are JPanels inside a JLayeredPanel and I'm setting the background colors to change the color. I'd like for the black keys to stay on top when I click the bottom keys. Is there any way I can do this? I'm using Netbeans GUI Builder

Comment: How have you setup the layering? Provide a runnable example of your code which demonstrates your problem

Answer (score 2):

Start by having a closer look at [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html).  You need to specify the layer you want each component to reside, otherwise they will overlap each other

Just in case you miss it, they key factor here is the use of `JLayeredPane#setLayer`

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class TestLayer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayer();
    }

    public TestLayer() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JLayeredPane {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            ColorPane background = new ColorPane(Color.WHITE) {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(200, 200);
                }
            };
            ColorPane foreground = new ColorPane(Color.BLACK) {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(100, 100);
                }
            };

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(background, gbc);
            setLayer(background, 0);

            add(foreground, gbc);
            setLayer(foreground, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void doLayout() {
            super.doLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        public class ColorPane extends JPanel {

            public ColorPane(Color backGround) {
                setBackground(backGround);
                setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
                addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        setBackground(Color.RED);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        setBackground(backGround);
                    }

                });
            }

        }

    }

}
```